# Occurrence by Month

Tags: excel, countif

I want to count, how many times the item has been used in a years period and the criteria is month. For example item x has been used in January, February and August. 
Data in my table is arranged :

```
A:A - all dates during 2018 
B:B - all item numbers 
C:C - item numbers without duplicates
```

Comment: [Create a PivotTable to analyze worksheet data](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576)

Comment: Thank you!
I used pivot table to get the necessary result- it was easier the get a formula ready!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a column, showing the `=MONTH()` of the date.

You mention the usage of `CountIf()` worksheet function, which is fine, but you can also use `Subtotals` feature for this purpose.